# CDI: how to apply interceptor to library (third-party) code?

Tags: java, struts2, cdi

I'm working only in a Servlet container (Tomcat) with CDI (weld) and JPA (hibernate).  I've found many examples online of creating a "Transactional" interceptor:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE }) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Documented
@InterceptorBinding
public @interface Transactional {}
```

```
@Transactional
@Interceptor
public class TransactionalInterceptor {
  @Inject EntityManager em;

  @AroundInvoke
  public Object wrapInTransaction(InvocationContext invocation) throws Exception {
    boolean transactionOwner = !isTransactionInProgress();

    if (transactionOwner) {
      em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    try {
      return invocation.proceed();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
      em.getTransaction().setRollbackOnly();
      throw ex;
    }
    finally {
      if (transactionOwner) {
        if (em.getTransaction().getRollbackOnly()) {
          em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        else {
          em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private boolean isTransactionInProgress() {
    return em.getTransaction().isActive();
  }
}
```

And this works great on my local code.  However, I'd like to be able to apply this Transactional annotation (interceptor) to code I'm not writing (i.e. library code I'm using).  In my case, I was hoping to apply the CDI interceptor to a Struts2 interceptor to ensure that during the entire handling of a request, I'd have a transaction open.

How do I apply this Transactional interceptor to library code in this way?

**EDIT** This is something that I've done previously via Spring XML:

```
<!-- TRANSACTIONAL DEMARCATION -->
<aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id="transactionalPointCut" expression="execution(* utils.struts2.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.intercept(..))"/>
  <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="transactionalPointCut" advice-ref="transactionalAdvice"/>
</aop:config>
...
```

But I'm looking for the CDI alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This becomes difficult with CDI 1.0. You'd have to crack open the jar and add a beans.xml in META-INF, repackage the jar and in your war (I assume it's a war) create a portable extension to add the metadata interceptor annotation to the class. You'd need to observe  `BeforeBeanDiscovery` and add a new `AnnotatedType`. DeltaSpike can help with that part.

Comment: If it makes a difference I'm using CDI 1.1 (weld 2.0.0).  I'll look at DeltaSpike to help me create a new `AnnotatedType` within the `BeforeBeanDiscovery` observed event.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.